# Clicking on a link on Visual Studio pops up a window that won't go away

Tags: visual-studio, popup, windows-10, freeze

I have Visual Studio 2012 running on Windows 10. Whenever I click on a link that is somewhere on Visual Studio, a popup window opens up saying "How do you want to open this website?" Can't close it, can't move it, it just gets stuck there. I still can manage other apps. 
For example, below is the window I got stuck with when hitting "View All Setting" link on visual studio of an Azure website. How do I stop this without closing everything down through Task Manager.

[image: Stucked popup]

Answer (score 1):

taskkill /im openwith.exe with admin rights will get rid of this popup from hades.